# Linux на Rasbery_pi и обычное программирование

Tags: c++, linux, c, raspberry-pi

С платами типа rasbery_pi - еще не разу не имел дела.
На данный момент - не очень понимаю общего представления программирования на таких однопроцессорных устройствах.

Могите пожалуйста составить общее представление на примере rasbery_pi:

**1**)Вот к примеру у rasbery_pi - есть официальная ОС "rasbian", но на rasbery_pi - устанавливают и Linux, Debian, Ubuntu - но как ? Разве Linux, Debian, Ubuntu - это ОС не под x64 - архитектуру ?

**2**)Ну предположим можно, как то поставить Linux на rasbery_pi - получается можно писать или использовать код С/С++, так как я его использую на Windows к примеру ? То есть я могу просто скомпилировать код Libcurl и послать Http-запрос с rasbery_pi ? При наличии сети естественно. То есть к примеру 3G модем подключенный по USB к rasbery_pi - определится Линуксом и драйвера будут работать на Линуксе установленном на rasbery_pi ?

**3**)А как из этого установленного на rasbery_pi Линукса - "дрыгать" ножками rasbery_pi. Возможно ли светодиодом поморгать с ножки rasbery_pi из под Линукса ?

Как это все в итоге работает ? Сильно не пинайте за вопросы.

Comment: 1 - Линукс не только для x64. Raspbian - тоже линукс. 2 - Да. 3 - Гугл подсказывает библиотеки типа `liblgpio-dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. rasbian это debian плюс пара программ для настройки raspberry. Линуксы есть практически под все архитектуры. Нужно только добавить загрузчик и таблицу девайсов для запуска на пи.
2. Чтоб запустить программу на си её нужно скомпилировать. Или кросс на большом компе или поставить компилятор на пи. 3г модем нужно будет настроить, но вот актуальные 4г модемы заработают сразу как воткнешь. Драйвера будут работать которые идут в комплекте ОС. Но на некоторые вещи драйвера запустить не получится.
3. дрыгать ногами можно даже без использования программ. Прямо в консоле:

```bash
echo 24 >/sys/class/gpio/export             # вывести управление 24ой ногой
echo out >/sys/class/gpio/gpio24/direction  # направление - выход
echo 0 >/sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value        # выключить
echo 1 >/sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value        # включить
```

потом можно переходить на python, с, c++ ...

Comment: А почему на некоторые вещи драйвера запустить не получится ? Чем это определяется ?

Comment: Например драйвер на canon 2900 есть только для 32х разрядных x86. И нет исходников.